# yii2: Proper way to throw new exception

Tags: php, exception, yii2

Just for testing I have added this code in my model while setting the debug = true and false.

```
if($packagedays < 1)
     {
      throw new \yii\base\Exception( "package days cannot be less than 1" );
     }
```

Now when Yii debug is true: I am getting

**Exception – yii\base\Exception
package days cannot be less than 1**

But when I am setting the debug to false
I am getting 
Exception
`An internal server error occurred.`

The above error occurred while the Web server was processing your request.

What I want is to replace the `An internal server error occurred.`
with
`package days cannot be less than 1` when `debug=false`

What I am missing here?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure you want to throw an exception here? This looks a lot like a use case for [input validation](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-input-validation.html).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should simply throw a `UserException` :

> UserException is the base class for exceptions that are meant to be shown to end users.

Read more : http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-base-userexception.html

Comment: Thanks Soju, Works perfectly the way I wanted.