# Defining new Exceptions on Yii2

Tags: php, yii2

I'm developing some web services with Yii2 framework.

When I was writting one of the functionalities of a controller, I defined a custom exception that extends Exception on the same file as controller.

```
class CustomException extends Exception {}
```

Then I saw that I need the same exception for other controllers. 
And I think: DRY!

I created a file CustomExceptions.php on \components with:

```
namespace app\components;
```

The problem is that now I'm importing this exception with 'use' key:

```
use \app\components\CustomException;
```

It seems that everything works well, and my IDE (JetBrains) is able to find the custom exception code.

But then when I run this code It fails.

I don't know why but It seems that It can't find this class.

What I'm doing wrong?

Thanks!!

Comment: This "use \app\components\ExampleCustomException;" should not be "use \app\components\CustomException;" ?

Comment: It is a mistake produced while I was writing the question. It's not the problem! Fixed! Thanks :)

Comment: Shouldn't it be `class CustomException extends \Exception {}`? Otherwise you'd be extending `app\components\Exception`, not the core php exception class.

Answer (score 3):

I found this: [yii2: Proper way to throw new exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28746429/yii2-proper-way-to-throw-new-exception)
So u can ovveride UserException:

```
<?php


namespace app\components;
use yii\base\UserException;


class CustomException extends UserException
{

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to

```
use app\components\CustomException;
```

instead of

```
use \app\components\CustomException;
```